# Using a Facebook Page ID to see Facebook Pixel stats

Tags: facebook

We are two people that want to use FB Pixel for conversion measurements. The other person went through the FB setup process and installed the script on our website. But I want to be able to view Pixel statistics in Facebook. Is there a way the Pixel info can be accessed using the ID for our FB page, so that we can both access the statistics? Right now only the other person has access from his own private FB account.

Comment: You both need to be administrators on the page.

Comment: sure, no problem. Should I post this as an answer then? :)

Comment: Yes, good idea:)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way the Pixel info can be accessed using the ID for our FB
>   page, so that we can both access the statistics?

You both need to be administrators on the page.